# Why can't I set headers with a curl request in PHP?

Tags: php, post, curl

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'somesite.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($body)
));
```

This returns the response *HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Content-Type: text/html;*

But I have the content type set to application/json as you can see above. Why?

Comment: Is there any error also previewed ? Like check the error log file

Comment: Is this url somesite.com JSON

Comment: @Hudixt — Why does it matter what the URL is returning?

Comment: @Quentin It matters what content is file holding HTML or JSON

Comment: Try with ContentType instead

Comment: try  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($body));`

Comment: @Hudixt — No, it doesn't. The server is refusing to return any content at all because it thinks the client is sending HTML. Since it isn't returning any content, it doesn't matter what sort of content it would otherwise be returning.

Comment: @RakeshSharma — Why are you assuming that `$body` isn't already encoded as JSON? How would changing the content of the body alter the Content-Type request header?

Comment: @Quentin i can't see any encoded code in OP posted question, i think if you using header for json then posting data must be json type. am i correct?

Comment: @RakeshSharma Thanks. Sorry, I should have mentioned that I already wrapped the string in json_encode.

Comment: @dan-klasson Thanks, but changing to ContentType made no difference.

Comment: @DarshanJain Thank you, I actually didn't even know there was a log file (that's how new I am at PHP). I had a look and didn't find anything.